# Error using atcom on raspberry pi 4: Can’t open serial communication

Tags: raspberry-pi, at-command, pi, modem, raspberry-pi-os

When trying to use the atcom command (found here: https://pypi.org/project/atcom) it keeps returning an error.

The error looks like this:
`[ERR] Couldn’t open serial communication`

I’m using Sixfab’s 5G modem kit and run AT commands (to view RF metrics, for example) without entering the minicom menu.

My command looks like this:

`atcom -p /dev/ttyUSB2 -b 115200 AT`

I was expecting an output identical to what I would get in the minicom menu, which is a simple:

`OK`

Instead I got the error you see above. Please help!

Comment: This atcom program seems to be similar to [atinout](https://atinout.sourceforge.net/). You could try with that program instead.